# How to check if Kendo UI ComboBox is Dirty (i.e. value has been changed from default value)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I have a simple Kendo `ComboBox`:

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <h5>Brand</h5>
    <div id="combo1"></div>
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
j$("#combo1").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    value: "Original_Brand_Value",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "..."
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the `ComboBox` has a default initial value of `"Original_Brand_Value"`. How do I check if the Kendo `ComboBox` is "dirty" i.e. *currently has a value other than `"Original_Brand_Value"`*? Seems like I should be able to do something like:

```
j$("#combo1").data("kendoComboBox").isChanged() 
**OR**
j$("#combo1").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.isChanged()
```

But I have searched far and wide and there seems to be no such method. There has to be some way to do this, this must be a common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have concluded, the kendoComboBox widget itself does not track whether it has been changed state. The datasource does have a hasChanges() method but making a selection does not change the datasource, it just gets a different value from it. However the kendoComboBox does raise events that you can use, for example 'select' that is fired when the user makes a selection: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-select

For example you could add this to your comboBox configuration:

```
select: function(e) {
    var item = e.item; //jQuery object representing the selection
    isDirty = true; //Set a flag or call a function as required. Perhaps check the item as well to make sure it isn't the default value.
}
```

Alternatively there is also a method called 'select' that can be used to get or set the selected item. You can use this to get the selected index (if it is not zero, then the comboBox has a non-default selection):

```
var selectedIndex = j$("#combo1").data("kendoComboBox").select();
```

This isn't the only way. If you were to use MVVM declarative syntax with the comboBox bound to a property on a kendo.Data.Model (which is observable), any changes will automatically set the dirty flag on that model: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#fields-dirty

MVVM is a very powerful design pattern to use with kendo but I think going into more detail is outside the scope of what you're asking.

Comment: I think binding the the `Model` is what I am looking for! Can you explain this more or point to an example (I've done a lot of research but still a bit confused)? I want to have 2 comboboxes, and when either one of them are dirty, I want to enable a "refresh" button. I thought I initially needed just a ViewModel, but maybe I need to bind the 2 `ComboBoxes` to the same `Model`, and then wrap both `ComboBoxes` and the "refresh" button inside a single `ViewModel`?

Comment: Oddly, I think the dirty flag on a kendo.data.model is one of the few things you can't bind to! What you could do, keeping it simple, is to bind a view model to your html, using declarative rather than the typical jquery plugin syntax for the widgets (as you have to do with MVVM). The comboBoxes then bind to datasources defined on your VM along with a binding to a function for the 'select' event. In that function, set a 'dirty' flag variable on the VM as suggested in the answers here. Finally, have an 'enabled' binding to that flag on the button.

Comment: MVVM is really too big a subject to go into further detail here and all I can do is point you at the telerik documentation. I always start here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/
Using it may well be overkill for what you need to do but I do think it is worth having an understanding of it since it can make life easier if there is a lot of interaction between elements on the page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion with with 'select' event, but there is one issue I see. What if the default value for combobox is 'A', then user selects 'B' (which sets the dirty flag), and then what if the user reselects 'A' again? It will be in the dirty state, but not really dirty. There is no clean way to implement this?? This is so hard for me to believe there is not built in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `value()` method to check the current widget value and compare it to the initial value, but probably this approach is not appropriate, as it is too obvious.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-value

Another possible option is to subscribe to the `change` event of the widget and raise a custom dirty flag in a JavaScript variable. You could even set an expando on the ComboBox widget object.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-change

On a side note, the ComboBox is an input widget that should hold and submit a form value. That's why it should be created from an `input` or `select` element, not from a `div`.